# Does RL methods converge with epsilon = 0?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

My question is simple. Does an epsilon equals to zero will converge to an optimal policy using RL methods? (with negative and positive reward function values).

Thanks,

Comment: Do you mean the `epsilon` in the DQN algorithm?

Comment: yes or simply RL algo

Comment: did my post answer you question?

Answer (score 0):

No, it does not. Because with epsilon=0 there is no exploration, and without exploration there is no guarantee. It is also intuitively sounds, since without exploration you cannot learn the environment well enough to find the optimal policy.

For example for the Q-learning algorithm, you can see the formal proof in 
`Watkins, Christopher JCH, and Peter Dayan. "Q-learning." Machine learning 8.3-4 (1992): 279-292.`
which shows that Q-learning does converge to the optimal values, if `\epsilon` goes to zero, as the number of observation goes to infinity.

Comment: Yes and no :) 
I understand in your answer that if I play infinity of time, even with eps = 0, I will converge toward optimal. My intuition is: we play a game and my actions are right or left and the purpose is to go at the end of a straight line (always right). Even with an epsilon = 0 I will converge because if I took left action which is a bad decision, as a consequence the agent receive a bad reward (negative) so automatically the next episode my left action choice will have a lower Q(s,a) than the right action, so automatically the agent will take right instead of left.

Comment: My answer is not "if I play infinity of time, even with eps = 0, I will converge toward optimal", it is the opposite. If you do not have any exploration, it wont converge. Beside, I am talking about a general environment, as you do not describe yours. If you have a given environment, it might be different.

Comment: Also, in your example, if you have even binary action, it still depends to the length of the episode. If the length is let say 100 periods, there are 2^100 states, and it is very less likely to hit the optimal solution.

Comment: In addition, if you have zero exploration, even if get a bad result with a given action, since there is not any exploration, it wont realize the other actions, so that it does not update the Q-value for the other actions, and it still selects the bad action.